# Google Objectify v4 fetch by id

Tags: gwt, objectify

I'm trying to fetch an entity in App Engine with Objectify v4 but it doesn't work.

- My @Entity: **Translation.class**
- The @Id of the @Entity I want to fetch: **301L**

My @Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Translation {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String text;

  public String getText() {
    return text;
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
  }
}
```

The request that doesn't word:

```
Translation translation =ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(Translation.class).id(301L).get(); // translation is null
```

But if I do:

```
 Translation translation = ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(Translation.class).first().get(); // translation is not null
```

Then:

```
System.out.println(translation.getId()); // translation id equal 301
```

So the **fetch by id** doesn't seem to work.
Where is the problem?

Comment: This works fine in test cases.  Are you sure there's not something more you aren't showing us, like a @Parent field in your entity?

Comment: @stickfigure YES, true, I have a **Parent** field in my Translation **Entity**. What does it change ?

    \@Parent
    private Key<PartOfSpeechGroup> partOfSpeechEntryKey;

Comment: Please read this carefully, especially the part about Keys:  https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your entity has a `@Parent` field, in order to get it by id, you need to execute:

```
Translation translation = ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(Thing.class).parent(par).id(301).get();
```

For more information take a look at [Objectify Basic Operations - Loading](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/BasicOperations#Loading)

Hope this helps!

Comment: What happens if you try to load by using the key of the entity? For example `Translation translation = ObjectifyService.ofy().load().key(myKey).get();` Also, can you add the code that you store the entity?

Comment: So here an overview of my Translation table's content in App Engine : [IMG](http://i45.tinypic.com/2zq9eep.jpg)

Then, 

Key<Translation> translationKey = ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(Translation.class).first().getKey();
Translation translation = ObjectifyService.ofy().load().key(translationKey).get(); // Not null

**So requesting by key works but not by Id**

And below how I store my @Entity

Translation translation = new Translation();
translation.setText("my string");
ObjectifyService.ofy().save().entity(translation).now();

THX

Comment: The problem was that I don't have the Entity's key. Just the ID.
THX

Answer (score 0):

for @stickfigure, this is my real @Entity (PartOfSpeechGroup is obviously an @Entity too).

```
@Entity
public class Translation implements IsSerializable {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String text;
  @Parent
  private Key<PartOfSpeechGroup> partOfSpeechEntryKey;

  public Translation() {}

  public Translation(Key<PartOfSpeechGroup> partOfSpeechEntryKey) {
    this.partOfSpeechEntryKey = partOfSpeechEntryKey;
  }

  public String getText() {
    return text;
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public Key<PartOfSpeechGroup> getPartOfSpeechEntryKey() {
    return partOfSpeechEntryKey;
  }

  public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
  }
}
```